# Convert DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS into MySQL TIMESTAMP

Tags: python, mysql, regex, datetime, timestamp

I would like a simple way to find and reformat text of the format 'DD/MM/YYYY' into 'YYYY/MM/DD' to be compatible with MySQL TIMESTAMPs, in a list of text items that may or may not contain a date atall, under python. (I'm thinking RegEx?)

Basically i am looking for a way to inspect a list of items and correct any timestamp formats found.

Great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the string into a `datetime` object and then output it back as a string using a different format. For e.g.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("31/12/2009", "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
'2009/12/31'
```

> Basically i am looking for a way to inspect a list of items and correct any timestamp formats found.

If the input format is inconsistent, can vary, then you are better off with [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("31/12/2009").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
'2009/12/31'
```

`Dateutil` can handle a lot of input formats automatically. To operate on a list you can `map` the a wrapper over the `parse` function over the list and convert the values appropriately.

Comment: Ended up doing this manually, replacing the list items as they were matched to a regex, cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `MySQLdb` (also known as "mysql-python") module, for any datetime or timestamp field you can provide a `datetime` type instead of a string. This is the type that is returned, also and is the preferred way to provide the value.

For Python 2.5 and above, you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime

value = datetime.strptime(somestring, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

For older versions of python, it's a bit more verbose, but not really a big issue.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

timetuple = time.strptime(somestring, "%d/%m/%Y")
value = datetime(*timetuple[:6])
```

The various format-strings are taken directly from what's accepted by your C library. Look up `man strptime` on unix to find other acceptable format values. Not all of the time formats are portable, but most of the basic ones are.

**Note** datetime values can contain timezones. I do not believe MySQL knows exactly what to do with these, though. The datetimes I make above are usually considered as "naive" datetimes. If timezones are important, consider something like the `pytz` library.

Comment: That works if you're already 'plucked out' the date item as a value, but I've updated the question to better reflect what I am looking for, thanks!